# C++ Base class initialize with member of derived class gives warning "uninitialized field"

Tags: c++, clang

I use a base class (A) that manages some data but without having the storage. The derived class (B) has a storage member and initializes the base class (A) with a pointer to that storage and the size of them.

The code model (clang) in the IDE gives me a warning "Field mStorage is uninitialized when used here" at line
`explicit B() : A(mStorage.data(), 10) {}`

Question 1: Is this a problem as long as I do not use the storage in the base class constructor?

Question 2: If this doesn't cause a problem, is there a way to avoid this warning?

```
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int* p, size_t s)
        : mPtr(p), mSize(s)
    {}

    void append(int i) { /* ... */ }

private:
    int*   mPtr  = nullptr;
    size_t mSize = 0;
};


template <size_t N>
class B : public A
{
public:
    explicit B() : A(mStorage.data(), N) {}

private:
    std::array<int, N> mStorage {};
};
```

Update:

- add template <size_t N> to class B
- My intension is to decouple the normal usage of the class and the template size in class B

```
void worker_function(const A& a)
{
    a.append(int(1));
}

// and also

struct Foo
{
    Foo(const A& a) : m_a(a) {}

    void do_some_work()
    {
         a.append(int(1));
    }

    const A& m_a;
}; 

void main()
{
    B<10> b;
    worker_function(b);
    // and also
    Foo foo(b);
    foo.do_some_work();
}
```

Comment: A base class's constructors should always be declared as `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work as you intend, but compiler warnings should not be ignored. `mStorage` doesn't exist yet at the time A is constructed. The base class is constructed first. Maybe the compiler, looking at `mStorage`, will peek ahead, so to speak, but that's not the required sequence. `mStorage` is probably just random garbage.

From the skeleton, it's hard to guess what the intent is, but you could easily solve the problem by making a virtual function that returns a pointer to the storage in the derived class. You may also find some sort of template solution.

I suggest you tell us a little more about why you want to design a class this way.

UPDATE:
C++ is unhappy not knowing what N is for a good reason. What happens when `worker_function` is called for the (N+1)st time?

I can think of two safer approaches. One is to make `append` a (pure?) virtual function. It won't be easy to write `A::append` anyway, not to mention avoiding a range error. The other is simply to use `std::vector` instead of `std::array` in class A and not try this fancy derivation scheme.

Comment: I updated the question to clearify my intension of class A and B

Answer (score 0):

You could use composition instead of inheritance and put the classes in the right order.

Note that I had to do some fiddeling with your constness to get it to actually work.

Example online [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:61,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:61,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%0Aclass+A%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++explicit+A(int*+p,+size_t+s)%0A++++++++:+mPtr(p),+mSize(s)%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%0A++++void+append(int+i)+%7B+mPtr%5Bi%5D+%3D+i%3B+%2B%2Bi%3B+%7D+//+My+guess%0A%0Aprivate:%0A++++int*+++mPtr++%3D+nullptr%3B%0A++++size_t+mSize+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Csize_t+N%3E%0Aclass+B%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++explicit+B()+:+m_a(mStorage.data(),+N)+%7B%7D%0A%0A++++operator+A%26()+%7B%0A++++++++return+m_a%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0Aprivate:%0A++++std::array%3Cint,+N%3E+mStorage+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++A+m_a%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Avoid+worker_function(A%26+a)%0A%7B%0A++++a.append(int(1))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+and+also%0A%0Astruct+Foo%0A%7B%0A++++Foo(A%26+a)+:+m_a(a)+%7B%7D%0A%0A++++void+do_some_work()%0A++++%7B%0A+++++++++m_a.append(int(1))%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++A%26+m_a%3B%0A%7D%3B+%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++B%3C10%3E+b%3B%0A++++worker_function(b)%3B%0A++++//+and+also%0A++++Foo+foo(b)%3B%0A++++foo.do_some_work()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.31070496083551,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.689295039164485,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int* p, size_t s)
        : mPtr(p), mSize(s)
    {}

    void append(int i) { mPtr[i] = i; ++i; } // My guess

private:
    int*   mPtr  = nullptr;
    size_t mSize = 0;
};


template <size_t N>
class B
{
public:
    explicit B() : m_a(mStorage.data(), N) {}

    operator A&() {
        return m_a;
    }

private:
    std::array<int, N> mStorage {};
    A m_a;
};


void worker_function(A& a)
{
    a.append(int(1));
}

// and also

struct Foo
{
    Foo(A& a) : m_a(a) {}

    void do_some_work()
    {
         m_a.append(int(1));
    }

    A& m_a;
}; 

int main()
{
    B<10> b;
    worker_function(b);
    // and also
    Foo foo(b);
    foo.do_some_work();
}
```